# MySQL: How to return only one row based on criteria within a resultset

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
id | group | value 
1  |   1   |   10
2  |   1   |   20
3  |   1   |   30
4  |   0   |   20
5  |   0   |   20
6  |   0   |   10
```

I want to return the highest value where the group is 1 (=30) and all of the values where the group is 0, into one resultset.

I have to do this in one statement, and I guess I should use an IF statement within a SELECT statement, but I can't work out how. Can anyone help to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look up GROUP_CONCAT function.

Comment: Can you post the result as you want it? Is it one record or several records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(select max(value) from the_table where group = 1)
union
(select value from the_table where group = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If (group +value) is unique, you can also do it without union (as proposed by **Ray Toal**)

```
SELECT a.value
FROM table1 a    
WHERE a.`group`=0 or (a.`group`=1 AND a.value = 
 (SELECT MAX(value) FROM table1 b WHERE b.`group`=1))
```